# streaming from HTTP source like google drive, wistia

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, youtube

sorry I'm not familiar with FFMPEG but I tried to do a live stream to youtube from HTTP source with minimum resources,can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code. I tested google drive as well but I got a this message:
"invalid data found when processing input"

```
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i https://fortminor3.wistia.com/medias/8tar9skdw9 -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 2500k -bufsize 512k -vf "format=yuv420p" -g 30 -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 198k -ar 44100 -f flv -s 854x480 -max_muxing_queue_size 400 rtmp://x.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/key
```

Comment: Can I ask why you think that ffmpeg could do that?

Comment: I 'm using a panel that manages FFmpeg commands to livevstream from multiple hosting videos like google drive and wistia

Answer (score 2):

ffmpeg cannot be used to read videos from random websites. For this particular video and website, you're lucky, since [`youtube-dl`](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) can download the video.

```
youtube-dl https://fortminor3.wistia.com/medias/8tar9skdw9
```

Then stream with the downloaded video:

```
ffmpeg -re -i "Borrowed video - Welcome to Wistia!-8tar9skdw9.mp4" …
```

Comment: I'm already working with this method, if FFmpeg cannot do this, do u know another alternative?

Comment: No, I don't. This is a rather special use case and `youtube-dl` is the perfect tool for that. Why do you need an ffmpeg-only solution?