# FFMPEG Why doesn't it work on google drive?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i "https://drive.google.com/file/d/15nJzaxD8uFvqqJqbIUHu_pE8JKla9g7c/view?usp=sharing" test.mp4
```

I need to **download video from google drive** and i **need** to do it **with ffmpeg.**

**Streaming link** or **video link** not downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I need to download video from google drive and I need to do it with ffmpeg.

You can't:

> ffmpeg cannot be used to read videos from random websites. For this
> particular video and website, you're lucky, since [`youtube-dl`](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/)
> can download the video.
>
> ```
> youtube-dl https://fortminor3.wistia.com/medias/8tar9skdw9
> ```
>
> Then stream with the downloaded video:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -re -i "Borrowed video - Welcome to Wistia!-8tar9skdw9.mp4" …
> ```

Source [streaming from HTTP source like google drive, wistia](https://superuser.com/a/1401875/337631), answer by [slhck](https://superuser.com/users/48078/slhck)

See Also: [How to download a Google Drive url via curl or wget - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48133080/how-to-download-a-google-drive-url-via-curl-or-wget)